# Modify registration backend Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a Prestashop 1.7 website.

I want to add in my db a column id_public for my customers with a random id with 16 characters. This should be created when a customer registers on the site.

How do I do this?

```
/**
 * Creates a default 16 char long hexdec string
 * @param number $length
 * @return string
 */
function RandomString( $length = 16 )
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not necessary, PS have a column called `secure_key` in the table `ps_customer`, you can use this instead a new one, of course this is a secure key (as column is named), then you shouldn't use this as public information, but you can extract the first 16 characters without problem and then you can use it as public.

Comment: Oh okay. Because I need this id_public for create a profil page for the public with link like that mydomain.com/p/id_public. What do you think ?

Comment: You can use my recommended column, just remember use at most 8 or 16 characters. Never all for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

1 / I recommend you do not modify the native tables of Prestashop, and created a new one.

2 / With the actionCustomerAccountAdd Hook, you will be able to add your key for a user

```
    public function hookActionSubmitAccountBefore($params) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'tablecustom (id_customer, key_random) VALUES ('.(int)$params['id_customer'].',"'.pSQL($randomString).'")');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where should I put this code ? I think is in classes/customer.php no ?

Comment: No in module custom, and greff the module on this hook